# find texbox value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hear is my HTML:

```
   <div>
   <input type='text' />
  <input id='mybutton' type='button' value='button'/>
  </div>
```

I want to find text box value when button is clicked:

Comment: m little bit know jquery..thats y.but i found great ful answers from here.. Thnks to all

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    var text = $('input[type=text]').val();
    alert(text)
})
```

Remember:

Add a ID to input text, by this way is is more easy find the correct element in the page

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    var text = $("input[type=text]").val()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/edavag/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$('input#mybutton').on('click',function(){
  var inputVal = $('input[type=text]').val();
  alert(inputVal);
});
```

You can also use a slightly more appropriate way to get the value:

```
$('input[type=text]').prop('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

If it always precedes that button you could;

```
var e = $("#mybutton").prev();
x = e.val();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have only one text box then try

```
alert(​$('input[type=text]')​.val()​);​
```

jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vh5Du/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Following Code for getting Text value using Jquery

```
$('#mybutton​​​​​').click(function()
  {
                             alert($('input').val());
 });
```

See the JsFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/nEGTv/10/

Answer (score 1):

You can select the textbox using `input[type=text]` but I do not recommend doing so as this is more of a genaralised selector and cover **other textboxes** too if they are present.

Instead, Give an id to the textbox, like:

```
<input type='text' id="mytextbox" />
```

Using jQuery:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    var text = $('#mytextbox').val();
    console.log(text);
});
```

Using javascript

```
textbox = document.getElementById("mytextbox");
mybutton = document.getElementById("mybutton");
mybutton.onclick = function() {
   console.log(textbox.value);
};
```

Comment: adding: `console.log` in an answer to an OP that ask for '*how to get a value*' is a really nice help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Without using JQuery :**

if your text box has an id as below

```
<input type='text' id="txt" />
```

You can use button action as below

```
<input id='mybutton' type='button' value='button' onclick="alert(document.getElementById('txt').value);"/>
```

Else you can use

```
<input id='mybutton' type='button' value='button' onclick="alert(this.parentNode.childNodes[0].value);"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

its easy way to get its.

using `$("input[type='text']").val()`

```
 $('#mybutton').click(function(){
            alert($("input[type='text']").val());
    });
```

you can also be get using [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) selector to get textbox

Diffrent way

```
 $('#mybutton').click(function(){
            alert($(this).prevAll('input[type=text]:first').val());
    });
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/Kfnjn/1/